# Save and retrieve an array of objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created an custom object "class" which holds data for my array.

Note: "data" is an NSMutableArray

```
- (IBAction)addNewTodo:(id)sender {

    DataHolder *dataHolder = [[DataHolder alloc] init];

    dataHolder.todo = _inputText.text;
    dataHolder.priority = @"%d", prior;
    dataHolder.date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [data addObject:dataHolder];

    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:0]);

    [self saveInUserDefaults];
}


- (void) saveInUserDefaults{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data requiringSecureCoding:YES error:nil];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"data"];
    [defaults synchronize];


- (void) retrieveUserDefaults{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"data"]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

The class which holds my data for the array.

```
#import "DataHolder.h"

@implementation DataHolder

@synthesize todo;
@synthesize date;
@synthesize priority;

@end
```

So everytime I run the "retrieveUserDefaults" method, the app is printing out:

> ...projlab[31828:5746912] (null)

And the output right after adding the data to the array is:

> ...projlab[31828:5746912] < DataHolder: 0x600001329540>

So how can I save and retrieve an array of objects in a correct way?

Comment: To be able to serialize a custom class it must adopt `NS(Secure)Coding`

Comment: @vadian Where do I add that? :o

Comment: You have to add it to the class and implement the required methods.

Comment: So I should add it to `DataHolder.m` ? @vadian

Comment: Adopt the protocol in .h or .m and implement the required methods in .m

Comment: How do I adopt the protocol in a correct way? Totally new to Objective-C. @vadian

Comment: @vadian `@interface DataHolder : NSObject<NSCoding>` like this?

Comment: Please read [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you just need to amend:

```
data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"data"]];
```

with

```
data = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"data"];
```

and then cast data to an NSMutableArray if you want to iterate for example

***EDIT***

Could you use the error parameter on `unarchivedObjectOfClass` to validate there are no errors saving?, one of the options is that your object is not using the `NSSecureCoding` protocol and failing before the saving

Comment: Alright, so when I tried your code I'm getting null.

`2020-01-22 18:59:15.882160+0100 labb2[32817:5841383] (null)`